# What is this heart in the crimson biome?

Tags: terraria

[image: heart]

I found this heart while exploring the crimson biome - what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a [Crimson Heart](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart). You can smash it with a hammer to get an item. Every 3rd Crimson Heart that you smash will summon the [Brain of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu) boss, so make sure you're properly equipped before smashing your third one.

Each world can have several instances of the Crimson biome, depending on world size, and each chunk of Crimson biome will have several Crimson Hearts. In a large world you can expect in excess of 20-30 Crimson Hearts throughout.

Comment: Someone plays a lot of Terraria! Can there be more than 3 in a server?

Comment: Oh...about 500 hours on record, so I'd say yes.

Comment: They're the Crimson equivalent to the Corruption's Shadow Orbs

Comment: @Mkalafut Terraria is an amazing game, so not terribly surprising. XD

Comment: @Waterseas Oh, I agree!  I just don't have quite that much time under my belt with it =)

Comment: @Mkalafut there are usually a lot more than just three in each crimson biome.